# Linux bash '[: -ge: unary operator expected' error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash


SubValue()
{


  romanvalue="${romanvalue}$2"
  decvalue=$(( $decvalue - $1 ))

}

if [ $decvalue -ge 1000 ] ; then
  SubValue 1000 "M"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 900 ] ; then
  SubValue 900 "CM"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 500 ] ; then
  SubValue 500 "D"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 400 ] ; then
  SubValue 400 "CD"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 100 ] ; then
  SubValue 100 "C"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 90 ] ; then
  SubValue 90 "XC"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 50 ] ; then
  SubValue 50 "L"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 40 ] ; then
  SubValue 40 "XL"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 10 ] ; then
  SubValue 10 "X"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 9 ] ; then
  SubValue 9 "IX"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 5 ] ; then
  SubValue 5 "V"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 4 ] ; then
  SubValue 4 "IV"
elif [ $decvalue -ge 1 ] ; then
  SubValue 1 "I"
fi
```

I tried this code and it gives many errors that

```
dectoroma.sh: line 13: [: -ge: unary operator expected dectoroma.sh: line 15: [: -ge: unary 
operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 17: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 19: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 21: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 23: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 25: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 27: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 29: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 31: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 33: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 35: [: -ge: unary operator expected
dectoroma.sh: line 37: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

could anyone help me to fix this problem please.

Comment: The initial value of `$decvalue` is `""`. Give it some numeric value.

Comment: And remember to use quotes [ "$decvalue" -gt 5 ] ; then

Comment: Side comment: The script seems attempt to print Roman numeral for a value. Worth mentioning that certain items I(1), X(10), C(100), and M(1000) may be needed more than once. For example, 2002 will need MMII. The current code will print up to one of those characters

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem reported in the question is an empty `decvalue` as [syme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58467844/12063049) has already stated.

Considering the purpose of the script, it seems you attempted to write a recursive function. For this reason, i suggest you to follow the comment under your question by jww regarding debugging!

Moreover, you are encouraged to search for questions on [recursive functions in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recursive%20function%20bash) on SO. There are excellent answers for factorial computations in bash.

Think about which quantities are "transported" and which are returned/compiled in the end.

---

If you are really stuck, you find 90% of the solution below.

```
#!/bin/bash
romanLetters(){
        local decvalue=$1
        local roman
        declare -i decvalue

        if [ $decvalue -ge 1000 ]; then
                romanvalue="M$(romanLetters $((decvalue - 1000)))"
                echo $romanvalue
        elif [ $decvalue -ge 900 ]; then
                romanvalue="CM$(romanLetters $((decvalue - 900)))"
                echo $romanvalue
        # ... and so on ...
        fi
}

echo "1900: $(romanLetters 1900)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `decvalue` is not set.
You are using variables outside of double quotes then all the commands `[ $decvalue -ge ... ]` become `[ -ge ... ]`, thus the error.

You can debug your script using the -x (debug) and/or -v (verbose) option to the line `#!/bin/bash -xv`. You'll then see and understand what happens. Instead, you can also call `set -xv` to enable debug locally then `set +xv` after the lines you want to debug.

Using double quotes, the error message would be a bit more explicit:

`bash: [: : integer expression expected`

Comment: I use double quotes and get the bash: [: : integer expression expected error. and I add another [ ] . The error is still there.  How could I fix this?

Comment: @GuangzheYang You have the integer expected error because `-ge` will evaluate two integer numbers. Everything else will cause an error (E.G. your unset var `$decvalue`)